# Getting most recent record and if the most recent doesn't qualify get the previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am new to sql, Am stuck at one point in one of my sql queries.My question is , there are multiple visit dates for a person where he has to qualify for some conditions.I have to pull most recent qualifying visit and if the most recent visit doesn't satisfy the conditions then it should pick the previous visit which qualify's.
ex:

```
name | visit_dt | x | y | z
 A     04/27/'17  1   1   0
 A     04/26/'17  1   0   0
 B     04/25/'17  1   0   0
 B     04/24/'17  1   1   0
 C     04/23/'17  1   0   0
 C     04/22/'17  1   0   0
```

In the above example qe need an output as below:
Expected output:

```
name | visit_dt | x | y | z
 A     04/27/'17  1   1   0
 B     04/24/'17  1   1   0
 C     04/23/'17  1   0   0
```

The condition here is we should pull the most recent of 'X'. If the most recent of 'X' doesn't have a 1 in 'Y' then it should look for the previous record where it has a Y as 1, and if all the records of that particular person doesn't have Y as 1 then it should pick the most recent of 'X'.
I think my question is clear. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Is that really the format of `visit_dt`?  What data type is that field?

Comment: You said "I think my question is clear"... maybe you intended "I hope my question is clear"

Comment: Please tag the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
    SELECT NAME
    ,VISIT_DT
    ,X
    ,Y
    ,Z
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY X + Y DESC
                ,VISIT_DT DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM MYTABLE
    ) B
WHERE RN = 1
```

Output with your sample data:

```
NAME                        VISIT_DT                X           Y           Z
--------------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A                           2017-04-27 00:00:00.000 1           1           0
B                           2017-04-24 00:00:00.000 1           1           0
C                           2017-04-23 00:00:00.000 1           0           0
```

Comment: @Mamtha: you should consider to vote for the answer (any one) that solved your question

Answer (score 1):

You can order by Y desc, visit_dt desc and use a CROSS APPLY solution:

```
select distinct(v1.name), v2.visit_dt, v2.x, v2.y, v2.z
from   visits v1
cross apply (select top(1) name, visit_dt, x, z, y
             from   visits
             where  name = v1.name
             order by y desc, visit_dt desc) v2;
```

The result is the same:

```
| name | visit_dt            | x | y | z |
|------|---------------------|---|---|---|
| A    | 27.04.2017 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B    | 24.04.2017 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C    | 23.04.2017 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

Performance depends on your indexes.

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/GUZS63889)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     [name]
    ,[visit_dt]
    ,[x]
    ,[y]
    ,[z]
    --,[RowNumber] (for testing)
FROM
(
    SELECT
         [name]
        ,CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE([visit_dt],'''',''),1) AS [visit_dt]
        ,[x]
        ,[y]
        ,[z]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [y] = 1 THEN [y] END) DESC, CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE([visit_dt],'''',''),1) DESC) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM
        [DB].[dbo].[Stack]
    WHERE
        [x] = 1
) AS [Visits]
WHERE
    [Visits].[RowNumber] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking some time and helping me with your answer.

Comment: No problem my friend!

Answer (score 0):

So consider `x` then `y` then `z` then `visit_dt`? Rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select name, visit_dt, x, y, z
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*, 
    row_number() partition by name order by x desc, y desc, z desc visit_dt desc) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking some time and answering my question